# How to get grafana alerts in ruby

Tags: ruby, httprequest, grafana

I am trying to use the grafana api (doc here http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/alerting/) to get the list of all the alerts in grafana.
Here's what I tried:

```
uri = URI("http://example:3000")
headers = {
    'Authorization'=>'Bearer test',
    'Content-Type' =>'application/json',
    'Accept'=>'application/json'
}
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request1 = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/api/dashboards/uid/uKH1CKVmk")
response1 = JSON.parse(http.request(request1).body)
```

This one works, it returns the json of the dashboard, but when I try :

```
request2 = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/api/alerts?state=ALL") or
request2 = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/api/alerts?dashboardId="+response1["id"].to_s+"")

request2['Authorization'] = "Bearer test"
request2['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
request2['Accept'] = "application/json"
```

I get an empty json.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks,
Nicu

Comment: You don't seem to use the `headers` in the requests

Comment: I forgot to add them, added them but it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, when I created the API token I selected "Viewer" permissions, I was thinking its enough to just make a get request on alerts, but apparently it is not, made a new API token with "Admin" permissions and it works.